DCMTK library configuration for android
I am trying to compile DCMTK source code to generate library for android platform and I get stuck on "Waiting until the Android device emulator is ready to receive instructions..."
I have macOS 12.5 with Chip Apple M2. Tried on another older mac but with same result.
This is my setup so far:

cloned git repository

installed Cmake 3.31.2, checked in terminal all good

created two emulators, installed NDK and SDK

run emulator

read doc wiki how to configure for android: https://support.dcmtk.org/redmine/projects/dcmtk/wiki/Howto_CompileAndroid

tried in terminal running with no success, stuck on "Waiting until the Android device emulator is ready to receive instructions...":
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" 
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE 
-DWITH_TESTING=OFF 
-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Android 
-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION=24 
-DCMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI=arm64-v8a 
-DCMAKE_ANDROID_SDK=/Users/xxx/Library/Android/sdk 
-DCMAKE_ANDROID_NDK=/Users/xxx/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/27.2.12479018 
-DANDROID_EMULATOR_AVD="Pixel_5_API_24"  
-DCMAKE_ANDROID_STL_TYPE=gnustl_static 
-DCMAKE_ANDROID_NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=clang 
-DDCMTK_BUILD_TESTS=OFF 
/Users/xxx/AndroidStudioProjects/dcmtk

tried using Cmake GUI with no success, stuck on "Waiting until the Android device emulator is ready to receive instructions...", but at least some files are generated in new made folder.
What is interesting is that when I want to select ANDROID_EMULATOR_AVD the dropdown list is empty! I added it manually but when running configuration the result is the same.


Am I missing something, have to define different setup or library has to be updated for newer sdk versions?
Some image files attached, generated files and how CMake GUI setup looks like.


